# Kamailio kamctlrc password encode

Tags: passwords, encode, kamailio

I'm trying to encode the passwords that appear in kamctlrc file. I don't know if it is possible.

Is there a way to do it?

Best wishes,
D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*kamctlrc* is the config file configuration file for **kamctl** and **kamdbctl** tools, which use it to get database info, default domain and some daemon config options.

It's a text file with ATTRIBUTE=VALUE formatting.

The passwords are configured in plain text in the config file, if you edit kamctlrc with a text editor (if you've installed from the repos it'll probably be in */etc/kamailio/kamctlrc* ) you should see fields like DBRWPW=password and DBROOTPW=password for the Database Read/Write Password and the root database password respectively.

[Here's an example kamctlrc file from the Kamailio team.](https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/blob/master/utils/kamctl/kamctlrc)

[Here's some info on setting up kamctlrc to work with MySQL database backend.](https://nickvsnetworking.com/kamailio-101-part-8-security-in-practice/)